# Assigning Angular $http.get call object to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Okay so, first of all, I'm pretty new Angular. I'm trying to get all of my documents (a JSON object) from CouchDB using a $http.get call. The JSON object is basically a list of people, with an id, their names and some quotes:

```html
{

    "total_rows": 2,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "5",
            "key": "5",
            "value": {
                "rev": "1-b26014051b18bce04ae2190d9cb92d81"
            },
            "doc": {
                "_id": "5",
                "_rev": "1-b26014051b18bce04ae2190d9cb92d81",
                "dataid": "5",
                "dataname": "Robin",
                "dataquote": "Blah"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "key": "9",
            "value": {
                "rev": "1-8ecbf37d0ccc129530e57747b46faa8e"
            },
            "doc": {
                "_id": "9",
                "_rev": "1-8ecbf37d0ccc129530e57747b46faa8e",
                "dataid": "9",
                "dataname": "Bert",
                "dataquote": "Hallo"
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

I'd like to show the name of each person according to the following HTML:

```html
<div>
    <p class="lead">Persons</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="p in persons"><a ng-href="#/quotes/{{ p.doc.dataid }}">{{ p.doc.dataname }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the controller and service I'm using:

```js
.controller('personsCtrl', ['$scope', 'personSrv', function personsCtrl($scope, personSrv) {
  $scope.persons = personSrv.getAllpersons();

.factory('personSrv', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

  return{
    getAllpersons: function(){

    return $http.get('http://localhost:5984/quotes/_all_docs?include_docs=true')
      .then(function(response){
        if (typeof response.data === 'object'){
          return response.data.rows;
        } else{
          return $q.reject(response.data);
        }

      }, function(response){
        return $q.reject(response.data);
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

I checked my debugger and the GET call works fine, but the problem is that the names won't show up on the page in my browser. I'm assuming the data that's been returned doesn't get assigned to the $scope.persons var properly.

Comment: Change `return response.data.rows;` to `return response.rows;` The $http then call receives data directly. Also just `$scope.persons = response.rows;` than that assignment. Remove `$scope.persons = personSrv.getAllpersons();` assignment.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fa6e411da26824a5bae55f37ce7dbb859653276d

Comment: tried using $scope.persons = response.rows; but my debugger showed an error stating that response was undefined. Changing response.data.rows to response.rows didn't work either I'm afraid.

Comment: `http://localhost:5984/quotes/_all_docs?include_docs=true` hit the url directly in the browser to debug what you get. response is undefined because there was some problem. The line '$q.reject(response.data)` need to be fixed - the `response` param of the that function should be `error`.  `function(error){ console.log(error); console.log(error.status);
        return $q.reject(error);
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$scope.persons = response.rows;` as `rows` array having a list of persons.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var response = {
    "total_rows": 2,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "5",
            "key": "5",
            "value": {
                "rev": "1-b26014051b18bce04ae2190d9cb92d81"
            },
            "doc": {
                "_id": "5",
                "_rev": "1-b26014051b18bce04ae2190d9cb92d81",
                "dataid": "5",
                "dataname": "Robin",
                "dataquote": "Blah"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "key": "9",
            "value": {
                "rev": "1-8ecbf37d0ccc129530e57747b46faa8e"
            },
            "doc": {
                "_id": "9",
                "_rev": "1-8ecbf37d0ccc129530e57747b46faa8e",
                "dataid": "9",
                "dataname": "Bert",
                "dataquote": "Hallo"
            }
        }
    ]
};

$scope.persons = response.rows;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p class="lead">Persons</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="p in persons"><a ng-href="#/quotes/{{ p.doc.dataid }}">{{ p.doc.dataname }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
personSrv.getAllpersons().then(function(data){

  $scope.persons = data;

});
```

Comment: That method works equally well, but I'm still not able to get the names on my HTML page.

Comment: is your call is returning the data  ? have you check developer console in browser for response of request. ?.. or just add `console.log(response.data.rows);` before `$q,resolve()` to check .. if data is coming or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `getAllpersons` function returns a derived promise that resolves with `response.data.rows`. The data needs to be extracted using the `.then` method of the promise:

```
//$scope.persons = personSrv.getAllpersons();

var rowsPromise = personSrv.getAllpersons();

rowsPromise.then(function(rows){
    $scope.persons = rows;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a success handler to run after you http call is made rather than returning a promise.

```js
.controller('personsCtrl', ['$scope', 'personSrv', function personsCtrl($scope, personSrv) {
  personSrv.getAllpersons(function(rows) {
    $scope.persons = rows;
  });

.factory('personSrv', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

  return{
    getAllpersons: function(success, fail){

    $http.get('http://localhost:5984/quotes/_all_docs?include_docs=true')
      .then(function(response){
        if (typeof response.data === 'object'){
          if (success) {
            success(response.data.rows);
          }
        } else{
          if (fail) {
            fail(response.data);
          }
        }

      }, function(response){
        if (fail) {
          fail(response.data);
        }
      });
    }
  };
}])
```